# Laurent series of $f(z) =\frac1{(z−1)(z−2)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series of the function $$f(z) =\frac1{(z−1)(z−2)}$$
in each of the following
domains:

(a) $\{z ∈C : 1 < |z| < 2\} $

(b) $\{z ∈C : 0 < |z−1| < 1\}$

I am very new to this but this is what I did for (a):

You can rewrite the function as $$f(z)=-\frac1{2-z}+\frac1{1-z}=-\frac12\cdot\frac1{1-z/2}+\frac1{1-z}=\frac12 \sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-z/2)^n+\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n $$

$$=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} (-z)^n/2^{n+1}+\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} z^n=\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\bigg(z^n-\frac{(-z)^n}{2^{n+1}} \bigg)$$

Is this correct? I will attempt (b) if it is. Please advise me.

Comment: The series regarding $z\mapsto \dfrac{1}{1-z}$ isn't right. Why?

Comment: I am not sure... what is wrong with it? Is it to do with the domain with 1<|z|<2 and not -1<|z|<1?

Comment: Yes, when you go from the fractions to the series, it's only good in $\{z\in \mathbb C\colon |z|<1\}$, which isn't what's asked.

Comment: So that means my other sum is wrong too right?

Comment: actually no, that one seems to satisfy the correct domain

Comment: So how do I make the sum such that |z|>1?

Comment: The other is going in the right direction, but it can only be right in conjunction with the one which you did wrong. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759164/complex-taylor-and-laurent-expansions/759188#759188) for a similar problem.

Comment: Ok I see how to do (a). Can soneone give me a solution on (b) please. I have no idea how to get the series of 1/(z-1)

Comment: For instance $\dfrac{1}{2-z}=\dfrac{1}{2-z+1-1}=\dfrac{1}{1-(z-1)}=\sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty\left((z-1)^n\right)$, as long as $|z-1|<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Your series for $-1/(2-z)$ is incorrect. We are given that $\lvert z\rvert < 2\iff \lvert z\rvert/2<1$ so
$$
\frac{-1/2}{1 - z/2} = -\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\Bigl(\frac{z}{2}\Bigr)^n
$$
Therefore, you should have obtained for part $(a)$
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\biggl[z^n-\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\frac{z}{2}\Bigr)^n\biggr]
$$
You picked up an additional minus sign. For part $(b)$, write
\begin{gather}
\frac{-1}{2-z} = \frac{-1}{1+1-z}=\frac{-1}{1 - (z-1)}=\mbox{what geometric series?}\tag{1}\\
\frac{1}{1-z}+\text{geometric series obtained from }(1)
\end{gather}