# Find Taylor series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ for $1<|z+2|<3$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

find Taylor series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ for $1<|z+2|<3$,

No matter what I do I reach the conclusion this series does not exist unless
$|z+2|<1$ but I don't understand why...

I can write  $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)}$ and then try to develop the series for each factor separately $f_1(z)=\frac{1}{(z+1)},f_2(z)=\frac{1}{(z-1)}$.

Both analytic  on any $1 \neq z \in \mathbb{C}$, so it must be analytic on the disc 1<|z+2|<3 since $z_0=\pm1$ is not in the disc...

So the disc should be an appropriate Domain to develop a Taylor Series...

But any series I find does not converge in it...

Can someone please explain to me  why is this?

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759164/complex-taylor-and-laurent-expansions/759188#759188) should provide a clue on how to attack this problem.

Comment: Thank :) I understand why you can find a series that converges in |z+2|<1, but I don't understand why there is no expression to converge in the mentioned disc...

Comment: Good.Now, in the moment when you decided that the series converges on $\{z\in \mathbb C\colon |z+2|<1\}$, divide top and bottom of the fraction by $|z+2|$.

Comment: Wow that was simple,I thought I tried it... Probably I did something wrong :) Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac1{z^2-1} = \frac12 \left (\frac1{z-1} - \frac1{z+1} \right )  = \frac12 \left (\frac1{z+2-3} - \frac1{z+2-1} \right )$$

$|z+2| \gt 1$ and $|z+2| \lt 3$ implies that we approach the expansions of the two terms differently:

$$\frac1{z+2-3} = -\frac13 \frac1{1-\frac{z+2}{3}}  = -\frac13 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left (\frac{z+2}{3} \right )^k$$

$$\frac1{z+2-1} = \frac1{z+2} \frac1{1-\frac1{z+2}} =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac1{(z+2)^k} $$

Combine the expansions and you are there.