# $g(z)=\frac{1}{3-z}$ - Laurent series for two differents annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series for the function $g(z)=\frac{1}{3-z}$ for the annulus $0 < |z|<3$ and $|z|>3$. I understand for the first case, the Laurent series would be $\sum_{n \geq0} \frac{z^n}{3^{n+1}}$, $0 < |z|<3$. Why for the second case, the Laurent series have to be different, i.e. $-\sum_{n \geq0} 3^n z^n$, $|z|>3$. Is there someone who could explain to me?

Comment: It should be a negative power in the second case. The reason is that if you factor out $z$ from the denominator you get $$\frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{3z^{-1}-1}.$$ For $|z|>3$, $|3z^{-1}|<1$ so you can apply geometric series arguments to it.

Comment: See, for instance, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/759164/complex-taylor-and-laurent-expansions).